# Excel VBA - Shared Macro, How to allow Developer Save rights 100% of the time

Tags: vba, excel

OK, this is a bit of an odd one, Is there a way for myself the Dev of the macro to have permission to save it all the time? even when others are using it?

It does not happen all the time but I Basically have a macro that 4 other people will have on there Excel Command Bar. This is saved in a shared file. Now If i am the first person in and quickly Log on and open Excel No problems.... If not I get a read only error when trying to save.

It is worth noting that the Macro is NOT saved in each users Excel roaming file, I did this on purpose because i knew i would be rolling out several Hot fixes and Additional content.

Is there a way around this?

thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: If you flag the file itself as "read-only" then you should be able to replace it, but other users will only get the new version when they re-open it.

Comment: Thanks, I Cant Believe i didn't try that already! Works a charm and immediately rectifies the issue. The Excel restart was always the case due to myself loading up my PC first this would Make me have soul rights, Whereas now this is not the case.

Comment: Its not not working, I have changed computers though (we rotate desks daily) No will not save at all. If i delete original and add another macro called MacroAddin will it be picked up by other users?

Comment: I would work on a copy and then replace the original file with the new version.

Comment: Tim, I have Taken some advise from [Here](http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?152-Deploying-Add-ins-in-a-Network-Environment) Basiaclly wht you are suggesting but raises some rally good points for Networked addins.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Williams Suggested, Making the file Read only in the file explorer options fixed the issue. The error seemed to occur due to the other user loading excel before the developer as such opening the Macro and Making it read only for themselves and locking out the Developer.